# dialogbox for server and client side asp.net

Tags: asp.net, client-server, modal-dialog

Hi can anyone tell me is there opensource dialogbox which can be used with both serverside and client side . Im working in dotnet 3.5 and i cannot update to dotnet 4.0 and im already using ajaxtoolkit v3.0.30512.20351

I tried to use [Proudmonkey](http://proudmonkeycontrols.codeplex.com/documentation) but I am working in ajaxtoolkit v3.0.30512.20351 and proudmonkey requires ajaxtoolkit v3.0.31106. and if I use old ajaxtoolkit my other functionalities will be disturbed . Now I want to know should I use ajaxtoolkit v3.0.31106 or use any other control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you can try to use Modal Popup Extender from Ajax Control Toolkit library. For example see http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx.

All controls from Ajax Control toolkit library related to Web Server control (extenders) with Client Side support (the other name for this type of controls is Ajax Control).

So if you will review the rendered source of the page on which Modal Popup is used you will able to find that the following client side component is created using the following js:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.ModalPopupBehavior, {"BackgroundCssClass":"modalBackground","DropShadow":true,"PopupControlID":"ctl00_SampleContent_programmaticPopup","PopupDragHandleControlID":"ctl00_SampleContent_programmaticPopupDragHandle","dynamicServicePath":"/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx","id":"programmaticModalPopupBehavior","repositionMode":2}, null, null, $get("ctl00_SampleContent_hiddenTargetControlForModalPopup"));
});
```

So, it means that you can create modal popup dynamically on client side. Also you can call specific modal popup behavior client methods using the following JS:

```
$find("programmaticModalPopupBehavior").show();
```

Comment: but how to use it on clientside also